# How to parse new Date(...) received in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I'm receiving the following JSON from REST service:

```
{  
    "data":{  
       "virt":false,
       "someValue":"0.0",
       "dateFrom":new Date(1519772400000),
       "anotherValue":""
   }
}
```

But I don't know how to parse fields with that `new Date(1519772400000)` object. `JSON.parse()` or `response.json()` doesn't work. I need to create an object from received JSON.

Is there any clean way to parse this without creating a new special parser or just using regular expressions?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, that is not JSON. If the REST service is supposed to return ***JSON***, then the REST service needs to be fixed. If it's not supposed to return JSON, then you're probably meant to handle this differently.

Comment: what kind of backend do you use?

Comment: It's a big REST service based on Grails framework. ExtJS can parse stuff like this automatically. Do you have any ideas how to handle that kind of stuff? Unfortunately I cannot change this.

Comment: I created simple method which uses RegExp `const pattern = /new Date\([0-9]*\)/g;` to find all occurences of `new Date(...)`. Then it parses input, sets date format and return correctly formatted json. I wanted to solve it in better way, but it's fast and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be storing and getting a JSON like this:

```
{  
    "data":{  
       "virt":false,
       "someValue":"0.0",
       "dateFrom": 1519772400000,
       "anotherValue":""
   }
}
```

Whatever you have posted in your question is an invalid JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, that works as intended, nothing wrong with the REST output.

[EDIT] Sure, it would have been better if it came out as a Unixtimestamp, or similar output.[/EDIT]

This is how you parse it:

```
let json = {  
    "data":{  
       "virt":false,
       "someValue":"0.0",
       "dateFrom":new Date(1519772400000),
       "anotherValue":""
   }
}

let date = json.data.dateFrom

console.log(date)
console.log(Date.parse(date))
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdn07jct/1/)

Comment: Unless the JSON string is parsed you can not access it like 'json.data.dateFrom'

Comment: Browsers auto-parses it, tried and tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE

Comment: And how does the browser auto-parse it if you receive the "JSON" as text in an AJAX request?

Comment: do a console.log of the json, and you'll see.

Comment: even if your browser or framework is auto parsing json responses, the parsing will fail in this case!